Accessibility issue - the screen reader announces incorrect information after submission
I'm using NextJS and I'm having an issue with the Screen Reader. When the modal is opened, it reads everything correctly. However, after submitting the formik on the modal, it narrates the footer CTA button, which is not supposed to be narrated, and then navigates to the right page.
I attempted to use useEffect on the next page. I also tried using aria-hidden for the CTA button when formik.submitForm() was called. I attempted many things, but I'm unsure where the problem lies.
